# Sorting table by specific attribute

Tags: sql-server

i writing query to find student grade in each course he takes
i need also to sort display student in their ID order and i need to but an extra attribute which shows his order based on his Mark

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[REPStudentMarks] 
(
@pClassID int,
@pSectionID int = null
)
AS
--Users.ClassID,  Users.SectionID,
SELECT Users.FirstName,  courses.Name, sum(UserExams.StudentMark) Mark, 
       ClassCourses.Minmark, ClassCourses.Maxmark
FROM courses 
INNER JOIN Exams ON courses.CourseID = Exams.CourseID 
INNER JOINUserExams ON Exams.ExamID = UserExams.ExamID 
INNER JOIN Users ON UserExams.UserID = Users.UserID 
INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON courses.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID 
       AND Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID 
       AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
--  where Users.userID=1                    
group by Users.FirstName,courses.Name,ClassCourses.Minmark,ClassCourses.Maxmark,Users.ClassID,Users.SectionID
order by mark,Name desc
```

the row i get after exec this query is like this

```
FirstName, cName, sum(UserExams.StudentMark) Mark, Minmark, Maxmark,'Class Rankings', 'SectionRankings'
```

sam,Math,90.0,50.0,100.0,1,1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not ORDER the table by two attributes simultaneously by ID and Marks. I am saying this because, what if the order contradicts the two attributes.

Comment: You can use to attribute in order by and gives u no error
but i my case i need to order by UserID but the second order is not through order by i need some algorithm to sort them based on their Mark, i mean if sam got the highest mark within the whole class then Class Rankings is 1 
and dean got the 5th highest mark within the whole class then Class Rankings is 5 and so on

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to say. You got results ordered by UserID. Now if by some algorithm you sorted the result on basis of Marks, then ordering by UserID doesn't make sense. right ?

You can Order by Marks and add addition column in result set 'rank' which is basically incremented value on each row (s.no you say)

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest to write a different query which returns the students by their Mark and do a `UNION` between the output tables.

See more information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191141%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)